# Ansible fail when condition not equal != not work on my play

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

The below playbook to check and compare input package name and version with our system when condition working fine on == but not works on != I don't why, And I'm stuck on this for the last couple of days

```
---
- hosts: "{{ cluster_name }}"
  user: sv_operator
  become: False
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /d2/local/bin/python
  vars_prompt:
    - name: cluster_name
      prompt: "Enter Cluster Name (Custer1/Cluster2/Cluster3)"
      private: no

  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: "Enter the name of Package and version"
      register: prompt
      no_log: yes
      run_once: yes

    - set_fact:
        package_fact : "{{ prompt.user_input }}"

    - shell: 
        cmd: "show system version | tr -s ' ' |  grep  '{{ package_fact }}' "
      register: svcli_output

    - name: Package Version
      debug:
        msg: "{{ svcli_output.stdout }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "PTS package {{ package_fact | upper}} match with existed one on the system"
      ignore_errors: yes
      when:  svcli_output.stdout == package_fact

    - fail:
        msg: "PTS package {{ package_fact | upper}} NOT match with existed one on the system"
      ignore_errors: yes
      when:  svcli_output.stdout != package_fact
```

Output when condition match (==)

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host-offline-01] => {}

MSG:

PTS package PROTOCOLS 20.12.01 match with existed one on the system

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [host-offline-01]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
host-offline-01             : ok=6    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Output when condition did not match (!=)

```
TASK [shell] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [host-offline-01]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "show system version | tr -s ' ' |  grep  'Protocols 20.12.02' ",
    "delta": "0:00:00.324347",
    "end": "2021-01-24 18:58:44.685277",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2021-01-24 18:58:44.360930"
}

MSG:

non-zero return code

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
host-offline-01             : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with your when condition. Your shell command fails (`rc != 0`) and your playbook stops. Moreover, you should not repost your question in a new one when it has been closed: edit the original one and wait for it to be eventually reopenned. To a avoid this, I suggest you have a look at the help section starting with [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and try to write questions with all needed info from start.

Answer (score 2):

As @Zeitounator pointed out in his comment, the `shell` command is failing and the playbook execution is stopping. It never gets to any of the tasks after that.

This is the behaviour of the `grep` command. If the given expression is matched, it returns return code of `0`, else it returns `1`. As we want subsequent tasks to run even if grep returns non-zero code. We need to "ignore" the return code of the `shell` task. We can do it in two ways:

- Use `ignore_errors`
- Use `failed_when`

In the below example I am using `failed_when`:

```yaml
  - shell:
      cmd: "show system version | tr -s ' ' | grep '{{ package_fact }}'"
    register: svcli_output
    failed_when: svcli_output.rc > 1
  - name: Package version
    debug:
      var: svcli_output.stdout
  - debug:
      msg: "PTS package {{ package_fact|upper}} match with existed one on the system"
    when: svcli_output.stdout == package_fact
  - fail:
      msg: "PTS package {{ package_fact|upper}} NOT match with existed one on the system"
    when: svcli_output.stdout != package_fact
```